# Creating a view to transpose a column with special conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
key | attr    | value
----+---------+-------------
a   | status1 | complete
a   | status2 | incomplete
a   | zipcode | 12345
b   | status1 | complete
b   | status2 | complete
b   | zipcode | 54321
```

and I want to pivot the chart to look like this

```
key | status  | status_value | zipcode 
----+---------+--------------+----------
a   | status1 | complete     | 12345 
a   | status2 | incomplete   | 12345
b   | status1 | complete     | 54321
b   | status2 | incomplete   | 54321
```

but with an arbitrary number of statuses (i.e I can have status3, status4, and each key can have unique number of statuses).

Is there a way to create a view in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select key, value, attr, zipcode
from (select t.*,
             max(case when attr = 'zipcode' then value end) over (partition by key) as zipcode
      from t
     ) t
where attr <> 'zipcode'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

```sql
select t1.key, 
       t1.attr, 
       t1.value, 
       t2.value as zipcode 
from tableName t1
join tableName t2 on t1.key = t2.key 
                 and t2.attr = 'zipcode'
where t1.attr <> 'zipcode';
```